# Escaping punctuation in .csv file

Tags: android, csv

In my Logger class, which writes all the error, info and debug messages to a .csv file. I want to log a string containing punctuation marks. I have a method which returns my current android version like this:

```
public String getAndroidVersion() {
        androidVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
        return androidVersion; 
}
```

The logging is coded this way:

```
logToFile(String.format("%s;%s;%s;%s;%s\r\n", new Date().toString(), level,_processName, message, "\""+utils.getAndroidVersion()+"\""));
```

I expect the last column to contain the android version which is 4.2.1, but it convert it somehow to a data like: `04.02.2001`. I know that the return value of the method `getAndroidVersion` is correct. I tried to escape the character as you can see in the above example.

What is happening here, do I use the wrong escape characters?

Thanks!

Edit . When I open the .csv file in `notepad++` it looks like this:

```
Date;Level;Process;Message;AndroidVersion
Mon Jan 07 13:37:51 CET 2013;INFO;Splash Screen;Application Started;"4.2.1"
Mon Jan 07 13:38:00 CET 2013;INFO;Bluetooth MessageHandler;Incomming file from VMw-1001500;"4.2.1"
Mon Jan 07 13:38:13 CET 2013;INFO;Bluetooth MessageHandler;File Received From VMw-1001500;"4.2.1"
Mon Jan 07 13:38:29 CET 2013;ERROR;BluetoothCommunicator;socket closed;"4.2.1"
Mon Jan 07 13:38:29 CET 2013;ERROR;BluetoothCommunicator;read failed, socket might closed, read ret: -1;"4.2.1"
```

This looks like it should, but excel formats my .csv wrong somehow?

Comment: Hi, you see "04.02.2001" in your csv file opened with some text editor ( like notepad) or you see it when csv file are imported and parsed in exel or open office?

Comment: CSV haven't types so you cann't say how the program must interpretate the value on import. One posible way is to format the column after import, or to convert the value in csv into another string that cann't be threded as data. Maybe with adding a + or space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a "feature" of Excel which automatically parse strings that look like a date as dates. Nothing wrong with your CSV.

I'm not sure how to turn that off in Excel though but this question might help you: [Excel changes date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906626/excel-changes-date-formats). I guess when you import the CSV you can "pre-format the date column as text". YMMV.

Comment: I just added a "V" in front of the version number. And the problem is gone. Thanks.