# Export PHP table with pagination to EXCEL, PDF, PRINTABLE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

How can I export my php table with pagination into excel and pdf format? I've tried many plugins and tutorials on youtube still no luck but they only get the data displayed not the entire table itself. I want to export my table to at least printable version better if I can convert my table into PDF or Excel Format. On my table I have a maxium of 100 rows paginated with 10 rows per page. How can I do this? I need your expertise.

[image: Here is the screen shot of the table]

PHP Export to branch:

```
<?php

include "connect.php";
require('lib/js/fpdf.php');

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tblSales");

$header = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT UCASE('date','sales') 
    FROM 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'.'COLUMNS' 
    WHERE 'TABLE_SCHEMA'='DB_NAME' 
    AND 'TABLE_NAME'='tblSales'
    and 'COLUMN_NAME' in ('date','sales')");

    $pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
foreach($header as $heading) {
    foreach($heading as $column_heading)
        $pdf->Cell(95,12,$column_heading,1);
}
foreach($result as $row) {
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach($row as $column)
        $pdf->Cell(95,12,$column,1);
}
$pdf->Output();


?>
```

AJAX Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.export-branch-excel', function () {
    var branch = $("#branch-hidden-data").val();
    $.ajax ({
        url:"export-branch-excel.php",
        data: "id="+branch,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            window.location = "export-branch-excel.php";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am confused about your question. You want to export the database table or the data displayed only  on the html table.

Comment: @SushankPokharel the data in my table

Comment: Do you want to download only the 10 item shown in your table at a time when the user click export button

Comment: @SushankPokharel I want to download all  100 datas

Comment: then see the code I have given below in the answer. It will download all the 100 data. Change the query and the database name. Save the below code in new page (Suppose named it as export.php). Then try it.

Comment: Sorry can you revise the code for procedural php im not yet familiar with PDO type

Comment: wait some time.

Comment: @SushankPokharel The code worked! the problem now is converting to PDF

Comment: @SushankPokharel please the revised code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@lawrence agulto I changed this code to procedural type as you said. Try this code.

> Download In excel:

```
            <?php

            include_once "connect.php";

                $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tblSales ORDER BY date DESC ");


                $columnHeader = "Column Name"."\t"."Column Name1"."\t"."Column Name2"."\t"."Column Name3"."\t";

                $setData='';
                if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                    while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        $rowData = '';

                        foreach ($rec as $value) {
                            $value = '"'.$value.'"'."\t";
                            $rowData.=$value;
                        }
                        $setData.=trim($rowData)."\n";
                    }
                }


                header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Nobelz_Sushank.xls");
                header("Pragme: no-cache");
                header("Expires: 0");

                echo "\t\tSales Data\n";
                echo ucwords($columnHeader)."\n".$setData."\n";
            ?>
```

> Download in pdf :

[Download the FPDF library from here.](http://www.fpdf.org/en/download.php)

And change the **query, table name, and TABLE_COLUMN_NAME** according to your need.

```
    <?php

    $result = mysqli_query($conn," Your QUery");

    $header = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT UCASE(`COLUMN_NAME`) 
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='DB_NAME' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='TABLE_NAME'
    and `COLUMN_NAME` in ('TABLE_COLUMN_NAME','TABLE_COLUMN_NAME1', 'TABLE_COLUMN_NAME2', 'TABLE_COLUMN_NAME3')");


    require('fpdf181/fpdf.php');

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    foreach($header as $heading) {
        foreach($heading as $column_heading)
            $pdf->Cell(95,12,$column_heading,1);
    }
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $pdf->Ln();
        foreach($row as $column)
            $pdf->Cell(95,12,$column,1);
    }
    $pdf->Output();
  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try this code I hope i works

Comment: Sure try this code. It will work. If problem occurs than you can ask me again.

Comment: It *will* work, but in case your data gets more complex, you may want to leverage `fputcsv` to avoid several conversion troubles. See e.g. https://coderwall.com/p/zvzwwa/array-to-comma-separated-string-in-php

Comment: @LSerni how can i convert my table to PDF?

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto I have revised above code for downloading the pdf. Watch above code for downloading in pdf also. In the above code just write your query, and change the **DB_NAME** , **TABLE_NAME** and **TABLE_COLUMN_NAME** according to your need. Others no need to change.

Comment: @SushankPokharel Does is it need to be PDO type?

Comment: @LSerni Would you like to mention what type of  conversion troubles are you taking about. Are you talking about the file size between the .xls and .cs format or it is different than that.

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto I didn't have tried this code in procedural form so I can't say about that. Also in FPDF library the code is used in PDO format only. So I suppose you should use PDO at this time.

Comment: @SushankPokharel oh I get it now thank you so much for your help

Comment: @SushankPokharel I have another problem I need to get the value of a hidden input type. That data will be used in my sql statement how can I do that? I've tried ajax still no luck

Comment: **<input type="hidden" name="position" id="position" value="<?php echo $position; ?>"> **      After **$(document).on('click', '.export-branch-excel', function () {**       add            **var position = $('#position').val(); ** and change your **data** to **data : {position: position, id:branch },         I think this is what you are looking for. @LawrenceAgulto

Comment: @SushankPokharel re conversion troubles: for example if the more complex data happens to include emails, and you might have both `<joe@example.com>` and `"Joe Bloggs" <joe@example.com>` -- and the quote sign disrupts your `$value = '"'.$value.'"'."\t";` approach. Or text fields with carriage returns (or tabs). Or you have a date, and Excel decides that '01.03.2018' is a longitude somewhat west of New Delhi. I have had all these things happen to myself, and many more :-D

Comment: @SushankPokharel I can't get the fpdf code to work :( please help

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto What is the error occured. This code works perfectly for me.

Comment: @LSerni The code download the date in correct format in my excel. It is not showing conversion error for date to longitude (as you have said) in excel even when I am downloading hundred thousand of data. Although yet I haven't checked for the email. If I am wrong than the help will be appreciated. Also I will research in this thing furthermore in future again to make my  code better.

Comment: @SushankPokharel, some *possible* conversion problems I already referred in my earlier comment. It is not a matter of how many rows you download, it depends on their content: if you don't have quotes, carriage returns, tab characters, UTF-8 etc., you will **never** have problems. For dates, again, **if** you keep to Excel's format, you will have no problems. **If** you don't, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906626/excel-changes-date-formats (or google, say, 'Excel CSV date changes'). All these problems can totally be overcome, as the built-in function `fputcsv` already did.

Comment: Sorry the code works its my fault I didn't include all of the files that is why there is an error

Answer (score 0):

The subject is way too broad. What you need to do is:

- supply a download link on the page (which means that any parameters needed for the export need be saved in a session; OR you can do a more difficult "download after AJAX POST")
- the link will run the same query you use to paginate, with the necessary parameters (see above), but *without* the pagination. It will then retrieve a number of rows. Possibly a *large* number of rows. You are already 95% done on this.
- you use a PHP library (the [new PHPExcel](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) for flexibility and features, [Spout](http://opensource.box.com/spout/) for speed) or a templating library (e.g. [TBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/)) to pull these rows into an Excel file. **This is the part you need to flesh out**.
- send along the Excel file as binary download.

The PDF version is the same (if a bit more complicated, since you normally need to compose the PDF yourself - there are ways to do otherwise but require access to the server, e.g. TBS + unoconv), except that you use a PDF library instead of an Excel one. E.g. [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) or [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/).

For a quick result and if you don't care about a formatted Excel file (backgrounds, logos, borders...) you *can* replace the Excel part with a "fake" Excel - create a HTML table, a CSV file, or even worse a simple unescaped tab-separated blob of data, give it a XLS(X) extension and go. From my experience, this gives you the worst result possible: **something that works 95-97% of the time** <sup>1</sup>. Great expectations, periodically dashed, with huge maintenance backlog<sup>2</sup>. If it's a pet project, go for it; if you need it in a professional setting, take the time to do it right.

---

<sup>(1) the remaining 3-5% being comprised of UTF-8 characters, quotes, numbers and dates written in any format but that which Excel understands for import, etc.</sup>

<sup>(2) add date formatting. Improve quoting. Detect UTF8. Detect UTF8 which actually was ISO-8859-15. *Wait*, unescaped. And so on and so forth. Oh, and every time everything must be done *yesterday*. And why it *still* does not work?</sup>